# Change a Date Object's Timezone in Java?

Tags: java, date, timezone

Turkey has two TimeZone GMT+2 and GMT+3.
I want to change the GMT+2 dates into GMT+3, but I want to protect hours and minutes that in GMT+2 TimeZone.

I want to take hours and minutes, and then set these values into GMT+3 TimeZone date. At result there must be no change in hours and minutes but the timeZone must be change only. At function `toconvert` date is must be GMT+2 format, but the return value must be GMT+3 format. How to do it clearly?

```
public static Date convertTimezone(Date toConvert) {
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setYear(toConvert.getYear());
    date.setMonth(toConvert.getMonth());
    date.setHours(toConvert.getHours());
    date.setMinutes(toConvert.getMinutes());
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Date does not have a concept of timezone?? Perhaps use Calendar?

Comment: Some examples of input and desired output would make it easier to understand what you want the code to do.

Comment: I solved my problem, I learned: it is about DateFormat not Date. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java a `Date` represents a point in time, nothing else. This means that `Date` knows nothing about how it is printed, which time zone etc...

Time Zone is therefore something you set when *printing* the `Date`. The class [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) is typically used for printing and the time zone is part of the properties you can set on `DateFormat`. Typically, people use the subclass [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Date cannot track your Timezone details. Use Calendar instead

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a Date object in this case. Use Calendar instead.

```
public static Calendar convertTimezone(Calendar toConvert) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, toConvert.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, toConvert.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, toConvert.get(Calendar.DATE));
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, toConvert.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, toConvert.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    return calendar;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use calendar.setTime(toConvert.getTime())?

Comment: @Adam He wanted to save the hour of the source date.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `Calender` API to convert one timezone to other

```
public static Date convertTimezone(Date toConvert) {
    Calender calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.setTime(toConvert);
    int hour = calender.get(Calender.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutes = calender.get(Calender.MINUTE);
    Calendar ret  = new GregorianCalender(timeZone); //timeZone is destination TimeZone
    ret.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis() +
            timeZone.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis()) -
            TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    ret.set(Calender.HOUR_OD_DAY, hour);
    ret.set(Calender.MINUTE, minutes);

    return ret.getTime();
}
```