# java print date different than the system

Tags: java, linux, date, centos, timezone

I need to set the system `date` in `Centos 6.6` so what i did

> cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime

And I wrote a small `java` application to print date and I print the date with the command `date` and i got this

> [root@sandbox ~]# date
>
> Fri May 20 19:13:32 CEST 2016
>
> [root@sandbox ~]# java t
>
> Fri May 20 17:13:35 UTC 2016

I really need to know why i have different time and how to fix it?

And i don't want to make change to the java code i want to fix the system date

Comment: looks like different timezones?

Comment: just a basic date print  ` Date date = new Date();`   `System.out.println(date.toString());`

Comment: @Orin2005 I know but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @omar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275811/change-a-date-objects-timezone-in-java give this a read. You can try and edit the timezone with SimpleDateFormat it looks like

Comment: @Orin2005 i don't want to change the java code i have a huge program it's not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first you should think of using @Basil-Bourque answer to change your code. it's a good practice

and for changing you `Centos` timezone try to export `TZ` to `Europe/Paris` like the following

```
export TZ="Europe/Paris"
```

Answer (score 4):

We cannot precisely assist you until you post the source code for that little Java app.

## Tracking date-time

One general concept you seem to be misunderstanding is that a date-time as tracked by a computer has no time zone. If you are using the old outmoded class [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), it tracks a number of milliseconds since the [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

## Date-time != String

Another concept: A date-time object is not a string. You can *generate* a String to *represent* the date-time value in your date-time object, but that string is distinct from the date-time. Remember, internally that date-time is actually a count of milliseconds since 1970 [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

Your app is likely calling the [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) method on `java.util.Date` class. That method confusingly applies the JVM’s current default time zone to the stored date-time creating the false illusion that the `java.util.Date` has that zone assigned.

## Default time zone

The default time zone is usually picked up from the host OS when the JVM launches, but not always. Configuration flags for the JVM may indicate another time zone as default. And any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can [change the JVM’s default time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault--) at any moment, *during runtime*! Because of being undependable, I suggest you avoid using the default, and instead always specify the desired/expected time zone.

Generally best practice is to **keep servers on UTC**. But I do not want my app to be vulnerable to such externalities as some sysadmin changing the server’s time zone, I always specify the desired/expected time zone in my Java code (shown further down).

## No problem

So **you have no problem to fix**. Paris time (CEST) of `19:13:3x` is two hours ahead of UTC, which your Java app is correctly showing as `17:13:3x` for UTC time zone. These values make sense. These two date-time strings are two different representations of *the very same moment* on the timeline.

If you want a Paris time in your Java app, ask for a Paris time (shown further down below). If you want UTC, ask for UTC in your Java app (also shown further down).

As to why your Java app is showing the time in UTC remains a mystery until you show us your source code.

In the mean time, I can show the basics of capturing the current time and adjusting into a desired time zone.

## java.time

You are use old date-time classes that have proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them. These old classes have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of the java.time functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in ThreeTen-Backport and further adapted to Android in ThreeTenABP.

An `Instant` is the current moment on the timeline in UTC, with resolution of nanoseconds (finer than the milliseconds in java.util.Date).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Generally best to much of your business logic, database storage, other storage, and data exchange in UTC. So make frequent use of `Instant`.

### Wall-clock time

Apply a time zone to get the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) for some locality. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

### Generating ISO 8601 strings

The `toString` methods in java.time by default generate strings in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class’ [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString--) method extends the standard by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-05-21T00:52:53.375Z

```
String output = zdt.toString();
```

> 2016-05-21T02:52:53.375+02:00[Europe/Paris]

You can adjust into yet another time zone. Notice the date being previous to that of Paris, `20` versus `21` of May (still “yesterday” in Montréal).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_Montréal = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

> 2016-05-20T20:52:53.375-04:00[America/Montreal]

So we have generated three different textual representations of the very same moment on the timeline (UTC, Paris, & Montréal).

### Time zones

Avoid using 3-4 letter zone abbreviations like `CEST`. These are neither standardized, nor unique(!). Furthermore, they are not true time zones. Always use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), in the format of `continent/region`.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't like or you can't change `java` code then you have to change server/system/centos `timeZone`, First you have to see list of possible timezones in

```
ls /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

and result

[image: timezone list]

see we have date `Sat May 21 02:54:11 IRDT 2016` we are now going to change you need to change (or set) the symbolic link `/etc/localtime` so make a backup of the existing `localtime file

```
 sudo mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak
```

Next, create the link:

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime
```

Make sure to replace `America/Chicago` with the directory (if your zone has one) and `filename` of the *timezone* you wish to use for example

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

Now you just need to test your change. Run `date` from the command line, i done it and result are

[image: UTC time]

and for see huge list of timezone click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: I did say in my question that I did link the file in /zoneinfo to /etc/localtime.

Comment: i tested in my `linux` system and change `timezone` and compare it ! now you do this `sudo mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak` , `sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime` two step and tell us whats happen  ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also check your `/etc/timezone` file and adjust accordingly